# jQuery issues with toggling/hiding

Tags: jquery, html

I went ahead and minimized a lot of my HTML code so you can see things easier, yes - it needs a clean up.

HTML CODE:

```
    <!-- LEFT COLUMN -->
<div class="column1" style="flex-grow: 1 !important;">
    <!-- APPRENTICE LIST -->
    <div onclick="console.log('clicked')" id="button" class="test1">
        <P>header junk</P>
    </div>
    <table id="table">
        <p>table junk</p>
    </table>

    <!-- JOURNEYMAN LIST -->
    <div onclick="console.log('clicked')" id="button1" class="test1">
        <P>header junk</P>
    </div>
    <table id="table1">
        <p>table junk</p>
    </table>

    <!-- EXPERT LIST -->
    <div onclick="console.log('clicked')" id="button2" class="test1">
        <P>header junk</P>
    </div>
    <table id="table2">
        <p>table junk</p>
    </table>

    <!-- ARTISAN LIST -->
    <div onclick="console.log('button3')" id="button3" class="test1">
        <P>header junk</P>
    </div>
    <table id="table3">
        <p>table junk</p>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- Middle Column -->
<div class="column1" style="flex-grow: 2 !important;">
    <!-- APPRENTICE GUIDE -->
    <div class="imagebox" id="box">
        <p>header junk</p>
        <div class="box3">
            <table class="test3">
                <p>table junk</p>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- JOURNEYMAN GUIDE -->
    <div class="imagebox" id="box1">
        <p>header junk</p>
        <div class="box3">
            <table class="test3">
                <p>table junk</p>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- EXPERT GUIDE -->
    <div class="imagebox" id="box2">
        <p>header junk</p>
        <div class="box3">
            <table class="test3">
                <p>table junk</p>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ARTISAN GUIDE -->
    <div class="imagebox" id="box4">

        <div class="box3">
            <table class="test3">
                <p>table junk</p>
        </div>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- THINGS TO KNOW APPRENTICE -->
<div class="column1" style="flex-grow: 1 !important;" id="ttk">
    <div class="body-flexstart">
        <div class="column1">
            <div class="imagebox" id="box">
                <p>header junk</p>
                <div class="thingstoknowbox">
                    <p class="professionheader4">TRAINER LOCATIONS</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- THINGS TO KNOW JOURNEYMAN -->
<div class="column1" style="flex-grow: 1 !important;" id="ttk1">
    <div class="body-flexstart">
        <div class="column1">
            <div class="imagebox">
                <p>header junk</p>
                <div class="thingstoknowbox">
                    <p class="professionheader4">TRAINER LOCATIONS</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- THINGS TO KNOW EXPERT -->
<div class="column1" style="flex-grow: 1 !important;" id="ttk2">
    <div class="body-flexstart">
        <div class="column1">
            <div class="imagebox" id="box">
                <p>header junk</p>
                <div class="thingstoknowbox">
                    <p class="professionheader4">TRAINER LOCATIONS</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- THINGS TO KNOW ARTISAN -->
<div class="column1" style="flex-grow: 1 !important;" id="ttk3">
        <div class="body-flexstart">
            <div class="column1">
                <div class="imagebox" id="box">
                    <p>header junk</p>
                    <div class="thingstoknowbox">
                        <p class="professionheader4">TRAINER LOCATIONS</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I present to you my terrible jQuery.

jQuery CODE:

```
 // apprentice 0
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#box1").hide();
    jQuery("#box2").hide();
    jQuery("#box3").hide();
    jQuery("#box4").hide();
    jQuery("table1").hide();
    jQuery("table2").hide();
    jQuery("table3").hide();
    jQuery("table4").hide();
    jQuery("#ttk1").hide();
    jQuery("#ttk2").hide();
    jQuery("#button").click(function () {
        jQuery("box1").hide();
        jQuery("#box2").hide();
        jQuery("#box3").hide();
        jQuery("#box4").hide();
        jQuery("table1").hide();
        jQuery("table2").hide();
        jQuery("table3").hide();
        jQuery("table4").hide();
        jQuery("#ttk1").hide();
        // show
        jQuery("box").toggle();
        jQuery("table").toggle();
        jQuery("ttk").toggle();

    });
});

// journeyman 1
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#table1").hide();
    jQuery("#button1").click(function () {
        jQuery("#box").hide();
        jQuery("#box4").hide();
        jQuery("#table").hide();
        // jQuery("#table2").hide();
        jQuery("#table3").hide();
        jQuery("#ttk").hide();
        // show
        jQuery("#box1").toggle();
        jQuery("#table1").toggle();
        jQuery("#ttk1").toggle();

    });
});

// expert 2
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#table2").hide();
    jQuery("#button2").click(function () {
        jQuery("#box1").hide();
        jQuery("#ttk1").hide();
        jQuery("#box").hide();
        jQuery("#box4").hide();
        jQuery("#table").hide();
        // show
        jQuery("#box2").toggle();
        jQuery("#table2").toggle();
        jQuery("#ttk2").toggle();
    });
});

// artisan 3
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#table3").hide();
    jQuery("#button3").click(function () {
        jQuery("#box1").hide();
        jQuery("#table1").hide();
        jQuery("#ttk2").hide();
        jQuery("#box3").toggle();
        jQuery("#table3").toggle();
        jQuery("#ttk3").toggle();

    });
});
```

Basically, without posting the CSS, it's a row with the info underneath

```
|LEFT COLUMN|  |MIDDLE COLUMN|  |THINGS TO KNOW|
```

Page loads with *Apprentice |LEFT COLUMN| |MIDDLE COLUMN| |THINGS TO KNOW|* already toggled.

Each button press should toggle new windows/hide the old ones under each column. The Journeyman Button works fine, but I can't seem to get it right for everything else.

I've seen jQuery code where it's a lot shorter and I'm looking to see how you guys go about doing that.

Comment: Working code in need of a review really belongs on the code review stack exchange.

Comment: Put the same class value for them and then hide them at the same time by doing `$(.class).hide()`

Comment: If that was what you were looking for then I shall put it as a solution

Comment: Here I'll help you once I can get to my computer.

Comment: Agree with @DaveNewton, there's a lot going on here. consolidate your html to make use of classes, it looks like most of what you're doing is hiding content on click, which can be done simply. Also,  you don't need all of those `(document).ready()` functions, it's just extraneous, just use the one.

Comment: @RandomChannel thanks, I see what you're saying kinda, but what happens when they're not all the same class? should i avoid using class for my css properties in the future?

Comment: with hide and show you can sort of push and pull with classes as well @krondog for example you could hide everything and just show `$(this)`    you can also negate what elements in the DOM are affected. I'm sure that previous poster has the right idea.

Comment: It is a good thing to use classes, and to define more than one class for an element, put a space between them when defining it.

Comment: @RandomChannel I see what you're saying, so something along thine lines of `class="imagebox randomthis"`? I just need to make sure that the the second class name shouldn't interfere with my CSS selector?

Comment: Also, to make it easier, cut down the HTML to the part where the problem is.

Comment: @RandomChannel thanks dude, I got it all figured out!

Comment: Yep! I'm just happy to help

Comment: @RandomChannel: would you summarise your answer theme(s), so that the solved nature of this problem is more visible to future visitors? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `$("#id").hide();` and using that for all if them, assign a class to them, and hide then like this: `$(".class").hide();`

Yes, using classes is a good thing to do when you are styling. It helps trim your code by a large margin, and using classes will definitely help you in the future.

To assign a class, use `class="class class2 class3"` where the space defines them as separate classes.